# Swift 2.0 beta trying to make UITextview be able to be dragged

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I got this error message: "-[UITextView labelDragged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a2bf400"
Here is my code:

```
var upperText:UITextView = UITextView()
 var lowerText:UITextView = UITextView()
private func addGestureRecognizers(){  
       let drag1 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: upperText,action: Selector("labelDragged:"))
        let drag2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: lowerText, action: Selector("labelDragged:"))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(drag1)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(drag2)
    }
func  labelDragged(sender : AnyObject?) {
        let gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer = sender as! UIPanGestureRecognizer
        let textView:UITextView = gesture.view as! UITextView
        let translation:CGPoint = gesture.translationInView(textView)
        textView.center = CGPointMake(textView.center.x, textView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: textView)
    }
```

This is my first time posting, please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to set the target to `self`:

```
target: self
```

Comment: It s still not work T.T. I'm trying to drag the textview only not the whole view.

Comment: Thanks very much I got it. Just my first time playing around with Swift 2 (y)

Comment: @Unheilig BTW, you need to add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to `self.view`.! You can directly add to `UITextView` and that was my concern!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to study how to add Gesture Recognizer to any View.

```
private func addGestureRecognizers(){  
       let drag1 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: Selector("labelDragged:"))
        let drag2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("labelDragged:"))
        upperText.addGestureRecognizer(drag1)
        lowerText.addGestureRecognizer(drag2)
    }
```

Replace your code with mine and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks! It's really help.